# Is it appropriate to ask about end-user website security?

Tags: discussion

My kid's school uses a 3rd party for handling tuition and fee payments. I've just realized that their password security is abysmal (they sent the password to me by both snail mail and email.  When I changed it, they displayed it on the web page).

I'd like to ask about what regulations they might be violationing (Sarbanes–Oxley, maybe?), and what I can/should do about the problem.  Is such a question appropriate for [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/)?

If it's not appropriate here, where would an appropriate site for such a question be?

Comment: If you ask question related to law and regulations, it is important that you name the country.

Comment: If it's a website that handles payments, I'm not sure SOX applies quite so much as PCI does.

Comment: @Iszi Thanks! Not knowing the difference between SOX and PCI is why I'm asking the question :-)

Comment: Question asked at http://security.stackexchange.com/q/8882/5868.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is absolutely in scope for our site, though I would say this is not really about "end-user" security.
This is about security of the website, and how that affects the users, is slightly different from your title...

But yes, your question would be ontopic.

Comment: The legal component of the question may not be fully answerable. Specifically if you want to use the law as a stick to get the school to improve security, we may not be able to provide the ammunition you need.

Comment: @this.josh We may not be able to provide a legal opinion on the matter, however I'm sure we have plenty of coverage for regulations - and, for that matter, technical-ish solutions for dealing with "well-known" legal issues (without giving legal representation, of course, or getting into any sticky lawyery implication questions).